# Toolbar title not showing in Center properly if Back button is enabled

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I want to show title of a `toolbar` in center so i am using custom `textview` to show title like this :

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Java Code :

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    title.setText("Title");
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Result :

[image]

Title text not showing in center properly if I am enabling back button of toolbar.

and things are working fine if back button of toolbar is not enabled i.e.

if

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Result :

[image]

Now , I want to show title in center with Back button enabled of toolbar also. How to do this ? Any help

Comment: Set _android:layout_gravity="center"_ for TextView

Comment: @PiyushGupta not working, still getting the same result

Comment: Then put textview in linearlayout and set gravity and layout gravity for linearlayout too

Comment: @PiyushGupta tried but same issue persist not getting any change in view

Comment: Use  `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Comment: @PiyushGupta no it's also not working :(

Comment: It should be work..

Comment: Not getting any change in toolbar title from all those suggestions, i have tried 4 to 5 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You need to remove this

```
title.setText("Title");
```

because already in xml file.

2) Use

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

3) Set layout gravity for `TextView`

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

**Edit:**

Also change height and width of `TextView` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: It will not happen. I have done with that and working fine in my case. Set textview height and width to _wrap_content_. Now it should be work ! @KapilRajput

Comment: Thanks man its working by changing height and width to wrap_content. thanks again

Comment: @KapilRajput Your wel come !

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest solution to this question is to change both the width and height of your TextView to wrap_content. Hope it helps.